# Resources 1.2.1 ERROR resource.ResourceMeta

Tags: spring, grails, grails-2.0, grails-plugin

Using Grails resources 1.2.1 I got the following error:

```
   2013-09-25 20:59:13,415 [http-nio-80-exec-3] ERROR resource.ResourceMeta  - While processing /bundle-bundle_appInfo_head.css, /plugins/app-info-1.0.2/css/table.css, /plugins/app-info-1.0.2/css/jquery.jdMenu.css, /plugins/app-info-1.0.2/css/jquery.jdMenu.slate.css, /plugins/app-info-1.0.2/css/tabs.css, /plugins/app-info-1.0.2/css/tabs-accordion.css, /plugins/app-info-1.0.2/css/appinfo.css, a resource was required but not found: /img/global/gradient/h300.png
    2013-09-25 20:59:13,459 [http-nio-80-exec-3] ERROR resource.ResourceMeta  - While processing /bundle-bundle_appInfo_head.css, /plugins/app-info-1.0.2/css/table.css, /plugins/app-info-1.0.2/css/jquery.jdMenu.css, /plugins/app-info-1.0.2/css/jquery.jdMenu.slate.css, /plugins/app-info-1.0.2/css/tabs.css, /plugins/app-info-1.0.2/css/tabs-accordion.css, /plugins/app-info-1.0.2/css/appinfo.css, a resource was required but not found: /img/global/gradient/h30.png
```

I also use the Grails Jquery 1.10.0.2 plugin and get the following errors in my production system:

```
2013-11-12 16:35:52,201 [http-nio-80-exec-11] ERROR resource.ResourceMeta  - Resource not found: /plugins/jquery-1.10.2/js/jquery/jquery-1.10.2.min.map
```

How can I fix these error?

Comment: You using app-info plugin. Problem from here https://github.com/burtbeckwith/grails-app-info/tree/master/web-app/css

Comment: h30 and h300 missed. problem not with resources plugin

Comment: @baxxabit it is from /plugins/app-info am I right?

Comment: #accordion h2 {
 background:#ccc url(gradient/h30.png);
}, but should be ../gradient/h30.png. You can add patch to Burt's plugin :).

Answer (score 1):

```
a resource was required but not found: /img/global/gradient/h300.png
```

- Try to put `h300.png` and `h30.png` to directory
  `/img/global/gradient`.

OR

- Remove from css declaration `h300` and `h30`.

It should fix an error.

Comment: I do not have this images. These images must be from the plugin?

Comment: Try to find declaration of h300.png in css files from /plugins/app-info-1.0.2/css and remove this declaration or put it here as update of question.

Comment: But the plugin should not have this bug!

Comment: the  Grails resources 1.2.1 plugin

Comment: you don't understand. an error is "a resource was required but not found", so grails resources plugin requires this images, when trying to bundle .css files. It find in css something like: background-image: '/img/global/gradient/h300.png'; and trying to load it, but it is missed. So, you need to put h300.png into directory or remove css declaration.

Comment: But you can see that the missing files are not from my app they are from a plugin like app-info

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38122/discussion-between-baxxabit-and-confile)